# GtkMenuItem - Empty space on the sides

Tags: c, interface, gtk, menuitem, gtkbuilder

I recently read that GtkImageMenuItem got deprecated and thus tried to create something similar following the advice of the GTK+ documentation of creating a GtkBox inside the GtkMenuItem and putting a GtkImage and a GtkLabel inside of that box.

It seems working, however, there is some space before the image and after the label I can't figure out how to remove.

[Please see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KuHN.png)

Here is my approach in XML so far (I'm using GtkBuilder):

```
<object class="GtkMenuItem" id="item_connect">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <child>
        <object class="GtkBox">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkImage">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="icon-name">gtk-connect</property>                                                               
                </object>
            </child>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkLabel">      
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="label">Connect</property>
                </object>
            </child>                                            
        </object>
    </child>
</object>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: it was the [reserve-toggle-size property](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenu.html#GtkMenu--reserve-toggle-size). I set it to false and thus the space gone.

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
<object class="GtkMenuItem" id="item_connect">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <child>
        <object class="GtkBox">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkImage">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="expand">True</property>
                    <property name="fill">True</property>
                    <property name="icon-name">gtk-connect</property>                                                            
                </object>
            </child>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkLabel">      
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="expand">True</property>
                    <property name="fill">True</property>
                    <property name="label">Connect</property>
                </object>
            </child>                                            
        </object>
    </child>
</object>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Unfortunately it doesn't work on my machine. It says: Unkonwn property: GtkImage.fill and GtkLabel.fill, and the menu looks a [bit strange this way](http://postimg.org/image/s07uuo8uj/).

Comment: Hmm, try removing the "<property name="fill">True</property>" lines while leaving the "expand" properties and see if that does anything. You may need to remove the "expand" property line from the GtkImage child as well. I use the C++ GTK inline functions, so I'm not familiar with the XML formatting.

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same except I don't get warnings but that's all. :(

Comment: Darn, sorry it didn't work. I do know that in programmatically desigining UIs, the gtk_box_pack_start() function (which packs a GtkBox with child widgets) allows you to set the expand/fill flags of the children, so that they fill up the entire parent space. You can also use gtk_widget_set_size_request() to manually set the size of child widgets. Maybe try to use that function on the specific widget you want to expand, assuming you are using C/C++.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your help and for the hints! I found what I was looking for and I posted it. Now it looks okay.